# Two monitors and a single X-Screen: How to change "full screen" center and resolution

Tags: x11, xorg, multi-monitor

I have two monitors, both 1600 x 900, running as a single x-screen.

When I try to run a full screen application (a game for example), the application full screens as though my two monitors were one monitor at 3200 x 900.

The center is then of course the crack between my two real monitors.

How can I run such applications so that they only use *one* monitor, 1600x900, centered on one of the real monitors?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you do not need the second monitor while your running your application, have you considered disabling the second monitor (using `xrandr` if your setup supports it) when you run the game?

If you are asking about an application you are developing, I am sure you can query the XRandR or Xinerama extension (whichever one your X11 is using) and then center appropriately. Most desktop environments support this already (that is why when you maximize a window it normally fills only one screen).